# Replace ending integer number of a function with another random integer number

Tags: python, function, random, methods, replace

I have a function that generates a random integer number between 1 and 6 and calls a function based on the number.

I have 6 other functions from another class which have names ending in numbers from 1 to 6.

I want to call the function corresponding to the random number I generate each time, because I want to reduce the repeating lines of `if` statements.

Is it possible to replace the ending number of a function with the random number?

Not sure if this will work though, I have imagined something like this:

```
sense.set_pixels(self.dice_(self.number)())
```

This is my current code:

```
def roll(self):
    sense = SenseHat()
    self.number = random.randint(1,6)

    if self.number == 1:
        sense.set_pixels(self.dice_1())
    elif self.number == 2:
        sense.set_pixels(self.dice_2())
    elif self.number == 3:
        sense.set_pixels(self.dice_3())
    elif self.number == 4:
        sense.set_pixels(self.dice_4())
    elif self.number == 5:
        sense.set_pixels(self.dice_5())
    elif self.number == 6:
        sense.set_pixels(self.dice_6())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method names follow a specific pattern as you say, you can use the `getattr` function to get the method based on a calculated name:

```
def roll(self):
    sense = SenseHat()
    self.number = random.randint(1,6)
    getattr(self, 'dice_%d' % self.number)()
```

But in this case it's more likely that you can combine your `dice_#` methods into one method that makes use of the dice number of the instance instead, resulting in more elegant code:

```
def roll(self):
    sense = SenseHat()
    self.number = random.randint(1,6)
    self.dice()

def dice(self):
    print(self.number)
    # so something with self.number
```

Comment: In anything but toy projects using `getattr` will make it very difficult to find out where a function is used.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, but the `getattr` approach makes sense sometimes, as can be seen in standard library modules such as `cmd` and `unittest.TestCase`.

Comment: Sure, but I guess it's used there because no better solution *exists* (unlike here).

Comment: @mkrieger1 It does exist. For example, `cmd` can instead be implemented by requiring the developer to use a class method to register the custom command methods into a class variable list. This is the approach taken by, for example, Django's custom filter registration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment everyone. (y)
I will definitely have a look on getattr, sounds right.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
dice = [self.dice_1, self.dice_2, self.dice_3, self.dice_4, self.dice_5, self.dice_6]
random.choice(dice)()
```

`random.choice` given a sequence returns a random element. If the sequence is empty it raises `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tuple:

```
def roll(self):
    sense = SenseHat()
    self.number = random.randint(1,6)

    dice_functions = (None, self.dice_1, self.dice_2, self.dice_3,
                      self.dice_4, self.dice_5, self.dice_6)

    dice_functions[self.number]()
```

Or event more compact:

```
def roll(self):
    sense = SenseHat()

    (self.dice_1, self.dice_2, self.dice_3,
     self.dice_4, self.dice_5, self.dice_6)[random.randint(0, 5)]()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not the right approach and I would prefer to encapsulate all the `dice` function to one which behaves according to it's input BUT if you insist on your solution, you can do the following:

```
sense = SenseHat()
sense.set_pixels(getattr(self,f"dice_{self.number}")())
```

where `getattr` allows you to get dynamically a member of a class by it's name.

Comment: That's the one I am looking for, thanks, it makes sense now~

Comment: If it helped you, please accept it as the answer in order to help other people struggling with the same issue :)